# How can I remove static cursor image from the screen?

Tags: graphics, lock-screen, cursor

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I am seeing two cursors(Mouse cursor) on my screen. One is active and the other is just fixed like an image. It sometimes vanishes and sometimes reappears. It often happens after I wake my system from sleep and login. When I take a screenshot it shows only one cursor.
 Please help fix the issue.

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu Server 18.04?  (thus text cursor), or Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 (thus it's cursor + mouse-pointer? or two terminals with cursor? or ...)  Please clarify

Comment: You could try reloading gnome. Press alt+F2, type `r` and press enter.

Comment: @guiverc mouse cursor

Comment: @pLumo that did not help.

Comment: [Refresh the X11 display?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14494/screen-corruption-after-hibernate-is-there-another-way-to-refresh-the-x11-disp)

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to refresh the screen and remove unwanted screen artifacts like a static mouse cursor image.

If that doesn't work try restarting GNOME shell. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then type `r` in the pop-up Run a Command window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell without interfering with any already opened windows.

---

Alternatively you can run the following to command restart GNOME Shell by replacing the running window manager:

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

This command won't cause any currently running applications to close or the current user to be logged out. After the GNOME shell restarts click anywhere in the terminal, and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key once before closing the terminal.

If that doesn't work try logging in at the usual login screen with Xorg instead of Wayland. Click the gear icon to the left of the  <kbd>Sign In</kbd>  button and select *Ubuntu on Xorg* from the dropdown menu. This selection will be persistent across reboots unless you switch back to Wayland.

[image: select Ubuntu on Xorg]

Comment: No  that did not help...

Comment: I posted an alternative solution.

Comment: no effect...I still see the static cursor.

Comment: Obviously logout/login will get rid of it.

Comment: yes but that is not a good solution